# Url rewriting for static .htm pages in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-8

I am moving a legacy website with hundreds of well SEO optimized .htm pages.
By default, it does not appear as though Blazor can intercept .htm extension files to run custom redirect, routing, or other logic.  This was once easy to do with the legacy ASP.NET Forms methods.  Do you know of a work-around by chance?

The goal will be to not lose the many backlinks the site has built over the decades by resultingly serving generic 404 error files when old links are clicked externally for the website, but I see no way to re-write or intercept this traffic through the standard routing practices.  More than likely because IIS is simply not calling the platform in this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the URL Rewrite module on IIS?
I think the two most common methods of url rewriting are:
1.Perform url rewriting by the asp.net request pipeline
2.Setting up rewrite rules using the URL Rewrite Module on IIS. You can refer to the official documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module.

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to dynamically handle this and run testing in Visual Studio as well through their localhost.  There are about 15 websites with this approach and to make manual rewrite approaches would be very painful.  Unless there is a dynamic way to do this that you are aware of.  [Calling an XML file or something of that sort].
Do you have a reference that you would like me to view just to make sure that we are completely on the same page?

Thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: It looks like configuring rewrite rules on IIS is an unfriendly task for you, I'm sorry I haven't found the way you want yet. Of course, I searched a lot and couldn't find the feasible method you said.

Comment: Yes that was my challenge as well.  Thank you so much for digging.

Looks like I may be stuck with generic 404 errors until Blazor becomes able to resolve for that extension like webforms used to :(.

Thanks again for the effort.  

I am all ears if anyone else has any suggestions. Microsoft?